# How to test the autogenerated java file using JUnit for my AIDL

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, junit, servicetestcase

I am using eclipse for writing JUnit test case for my project. My project contains a bound service based on AIDL. After executing the project i get an autogenerated java file for the AIDL, in the gen folder.

This file contains a Stub class which has methods like

```
    public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
    public boolean onTransact(int code, android.os.Parcel data, android.os.Parcel reply, int flags) throws android.os.RemoteException
```

and a Proxy class which has methods

```
public android.os.IBinder asBinder()
public java.lang.String getInterfaceDescriptor()
```

and also some methods created by me .  I want to test the above methods using JUint Test . Is it possible to test these methods using  [ServiceTestCase](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ServiceTestCase.html) or can i test this using some other method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to test the methods of my Stub Class using the following code in my testProject

```
IBinder service = this.bindService(new Intent(MyService.class.getName()));
        MyFile iTestServiceCall = MyFile.Stub.asInterface(service);
        b=service.transact(0, data, null, 0);
        assertTrue("Value is still false", b);
        assertNotNull("Value is null",iTestServiceCall.asBinder());
```

Here MyService is the service i created and MyFile is the Aidl.